# Assign column adding columns in pandas dynamically (method chaining in python)

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining

I want to create a new column named total which adds all the year columns (everything in these columns are integers). I want to do it dynamically because as each year passes there will be a new column (for example 2024).

How can I do this in Python using method chaining and the assign operator?

```
id name     2018 2019 2020 2021 2022  type
1  John      0    1    0    0    2    A
2  Bill      1    5    4    0    0    B
3  Tom       0    0    2    0    5    B
4  Mary      0    1    1    0    0    A
```

**Expected Output:**

```
id name     2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 type total
1  John      0    1    0    0    2    A   3
2  Bill      1    5    4    0    0    B   10
3  Tom       0    0    2    0    5    B   7
4  Mary      0    1    1    0    0    A   2
```

I have this solution but I don't like it, is there a more eloquent way of writing this code?

**Temporary Solution:**

```
(
     df
     .assign(Total = lambda x: x['2018'] + x['2019'] + x['2020'] + x['2021'] x['2022'])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select columns between `2018` and `2022`:

```
df = df.assign(Total = df.loc[:, '2018':'2022'].sum(axis=1))
print (df)
   id  name  2018  2019  2020  2021  2022 type  Total
0   1  John     0     1     0     0     2    A      3
1   2  Bill     1     5     4     0     0    B     10
2   3   Tom     0     0     2     0     5    B      7
3   4  Mary     0     1     1     0     0    A      2
```

Another idea is filter columns names by mask - here convert to numeric and test if column names are larger like `2000`:

```
df = df.assign(Total=df.loc[:, pd.to_numeric(df.columns,errors='coerce')>2000].sum(axis=1))
print (df)
   id  name  2018  2019  2020  2021  2022 type  Total
0   1  John     0     1     0     0     2    A      3
1   2  Bill     1     5     4     0     0    B     10
2   3   Tom     0     0     2     0     5    B      7
3   4  Mary     0     1     1     0     0    A      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with a generic regex for 4-digits year:

```
out = df.assign(Total=lambda d: d.filter(regex='^\d{4}$').sum(axis=1))
```

Or with [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.htm) and the columns to ignore:

```
out = df.assign(Total=lambda d: d.drop(columns=['id', 'name', 'type', 'Total'],
                                       errors='ignore').sum(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   id  name  2018  2019  2020  2021  2022 type  Total
0   1  John     0     1     0     0     2    A      3
1   2  Bill     1     5     4     0     0    B     10
2   3   Tom     0     0     2     0     5    B      7
3   4  Mary     0     1     1     0     0    A      2
```

Sorting columns and changing type of all integer columns:

```
out = (df.assign(Total=lambda d: d.filter(regex='^\d{4}$').sum(axis=1)
         .sort_index(key=lambda x: x.astype(str).str.fullmatch('\d{4}'), axis=1)
         .pipe(lambda d: d.astype({c: float for c in out.select_dtypes('number')}))
       )
```

Output:

```
    id  name type  total  2018  2019  2020  2021  2022
0  1.0  John    A    3.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   2.0
1  2.0  Bill    B   10.0   1.0   5.0   4.0   0.0   0.0
2  3.0   Tom    B    7.0   0.0   0.0   2.0   0.0   5.0
3  4.0  Mary    A    2.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to order the columns using method chaining and converting all integers to floats as well? For example I want the year columns at the end of the data frame

Comment: Is the final output what you wanted?

Comment: Yes thank you!! But also want to change integer to floats

Comment: @Eisen what you you mean? in "total"? `.astype({'Total': float})`? or `.astype(float)` in the `assign`.

Comment: I want to assign all inteteger columns to floats, but I''m getting an error when I do .astype() because of the string columns

Comment: I see, you can use `pipe` (see update)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the only columns with int values will be the year columns, you can just do `df['Total'] = df.sum(axis = 1)`:

```py
columns = ['name', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', 'type']
values = [['John',0,1,0,0,2,'A'], ['Bill',1,5,4,0,0,'B'], ['Tom',0,0,2,0,5,'B'], ['Mary',0,1,1,0,0,'A']]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = columns)

df['Total'] = df.sum(axis = 1)
df
```

Output:

```
name       2018    2019    2020   2021    2022    type    Total
0   John    0       1       0      0       2       A        3
1   Bill    1       5       4      0       0       B        10
2   Tom     0       0       2      0       5       B        7
3   Mary    0       1       1      0       0       A        2
```